# Update recyclerview with time on mysql

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

I have date time on `MySQL`. And I want to change the `RecyclerView` after the date time stored on `MySQL`. I can do that with 2 `view holder`s. But to see the change, I need to restart the `Activity`. How can I make this change dynamic? I mean, `view holder` will be changed as soon as the current date time passes the stored date time.

Answer (score 0):

update your RecyclerView by calling NotifyDataSetChanged of RecyclerView adapter when you receive the Mysql update response.

read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifydatasetchanged

Comment: I have populated the list. The time has changed after population.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was, I triggered my BroadcastReceiver class with the time from database with AlarmManager and as soon as It gets triggere, I updated the adapter with notifyDatasetChanged.